# No module named defusedxml.xmlrpc

Tags: ros, module

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using robot_localization offered by ROS downloaded from gihub .It can be compiled and I haven't changed anything of it. When I executed the command: 'roslaunch ekf_template.launch' in a terminal,I got several warnings as follows:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/pantiq/robot/devel/bin/roslaunch", line 6, in
exec(fh.read())
File "", line 34, in
File "/home/pantiq/robot/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/init.py", line 35, in
exec(__fh.read())
File "", line 56, in
File "/home/pantiq/robot/src/ros_comm/tools/roslaunch/src/roslaunch/launch.py", line 55, in
from roslaunch.nodeprocess import create_master_process, create_node_process
File "/home/pantiq/robot/src/ros_comm/tools/roslaunch/src/roslaunch/nodeprocess.py", line 52, in
from rosmaster.master_api import NUM_WORKERS
File "/home/pantiq/robot/src/ros_comm/tools/rosmaster/src/rosmaster/init.py", line 35, in
from .main import rosmaster_main
File "/home/pantiq/robot/src/ros_comm/tools/rosmaster/src/rosmaster/main.py", line 43, in
import rosmaster.master
File "/home/pantiq/robot/src/ros_comm/tools/rosmaster/src/rosmaster/master.py", line 47, in
import rosmaster.master_api
File "/home/pantiq/robot/src/ros_comm/tools/rosmaster/src/rosmaster/master_api.py", line 72, in
from rosmaster.util import xmlrpcapi
File "/home/pantiq/robot/src/ros_comm/tools/rosmaster/src/rosmaster/util.py", line 48, in
from defusedxml.xmlrpc import monkey_patch
ImportError: No module named defusedxml.xmlrpc
Then I downloaded a folder named defusedxml from a website,and put it in the robot_localization/src path,still it doesn't work.

What should I do with it?Shall I custimaze it or do something else?
I do appreciate it if anyone can help me out.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/260377/no-module-named-defusedxml.xmlrpc/) by [DaDaLee](https://answers.ros.org/users/30176/dadalee/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2017-04-26

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems like you're missing the `defulsedxml` python package; and it looks like your probably can't run any `roslaunch` or `roscore` commands as a result.

defulsedxml should have been installed when you installed ROS. If you're running Ubuntu, you can reinstall it by running `sudo apt-get install python-defusedxml`

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-04-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DaDaLee](https://answers.ros.org/users/30176/dadalee/) on 2017-04-27**:
Thank you so much that your proposal really works.But here pops up another problem:
After running the command: roslaunch ekf_template.launch , I run rostopic echo /odometry/filtered in another terminal.Then I got nothing.Does it mean that the node isn't operating at all or something else goes wrong?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-04-27**:
I'm not very familiar with robot_localization, so I'm not sure what's wrong. That sounds like a topic for a new question.

**Comment by [DaDaLee](https://answers.ros.org/users/30176/dadalee/) on 2017-04-27**:
Thank you Ahendrix.Maybe I should raise a new question about it.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Even I was facing a similar error.
Running `pip install defusedxml` helped me!

---

Originally posted by [Preeti Mukherjee](https://answers.ros.org/users/39686/preeti-mukherjee/) with karma: 41 on 2019-01-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-10-08**:
Please be aware of the downsides to using `pip` to install Python packages on a platform which normally uses `apt` (ie: no automatic upgrades, no visibility to the package manager, etc).

In general, use of `pip` for managing Python dependencies of (core) ROS packages is discouraged on Debian based platforms.

There are certainly legitimate use-cases for it, but it should not be regarded an appropriate solution to the problem reported by the OP.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2021-12-02**:
"under the hood" your python interpreter isn't able to find the `defusedxml` module on the PYTHONPATH.
Since your version of ROS uses python 3, you probably need the defusedxml apt package for python3: `python3-defusedxml`